# in Python, How to Redirect to previous page after displaying error page through function

Tags: python, flask

I'm writing a little program for a project. It has multiple pages each with user input areas, and its required to show an error page if the user input is invalid. currently it employs a helper function to render_template an error page. reusing the same error page for all error messages, i basically write a line like:

return error(message)

I think directing to an error page is not as user friendly and want to add an auto redirect back to the previous page after a short delay.

the only method i could find is adding:

,{"Refresh": "3; url="}

to my error function's "return render_template" in attempt to set the delayed redirect. but I can only make it work with hard coded url rather than a dynamic variable that changed back to the previous page.

and of course i cannot add the {"Refresh": "3; url="} to my "return error()" function individually...

can anyone figure out a method for me to link it to the current page always right after the error?

Answer (score 0):

If you added your codes here, I was writing a custom script for your need but you didn't sadly.

So I hope it will help you.

It's better to create a new route for errors and redirect user form other routes to it. You can use session to store error code and detail but here we are using arguments:

```
from flask import request, render_template

@app.route("/error-page")
def error_page():
    error_code = request.args.get("error_code")
    error_detail = request.args.get("error_detail")
    go_back_page_url = request.args.get("go_back_page_url")

    if go_back_page_url == None:
        go_back_page_url ="/" # it will redirect to home page if not set

    refresh = 3 * 1000 # 3 seconds

    ### add more codes here if you needed
    # HERE
    ###

    return render_template("error_page.html", error_code=error_code, error_detail=error_detail, go_back_page_url=go_back_page_url, refresh=refresh)
```

**Then**

Import `redirect` and `url_for` to your file:

```
from flask import redirect, url_for
```

and whenever you want to give an error to user in your other routes do like this:

```
return redirect(url_for("error_page", error_code="A custome code", error_detail="Extra information about error", go_back_page_url=request.url_rule))
```

And then you need a Javascript code to handle redirect.

`error_page.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Error: {{error_code}}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Error Happended!</h1>

    {% if error_code and error_detail %}

        <p>{{ error_code }}</p>
        <p>{{ error_detail }}</p>

        <script>
            var timeout_seconds = {{refresh}};

            function redirect_back()
            {
                window.location.href = '{{ go_back_page_url }}';
            }
            setTimeout(redirect_back, timeout_seconds)
        </script>


    {% else %}
        <p>Error is not valid.</p>
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

Ask any question you have in comments.